# Regex for unicode with a closing bracket

Tags: regex, unicode

I have this particular regex code u+4e39 which is this character 丹

I tried to only match string that has "[丹]"

when I tried in regex playground website,such as http://leaverou.github.io/regexplained/

I put this /[\u4e39]/g, it only selects the opening bracket and the character, but not the closing bracket.  the resulting selection is [丹

I also tried it with /[.]/g, same thing happened.  I don't understand why.

Please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape the opening bracket in your regular expression pattern.

```
var r = '[丹]'.match(/\[\u4e39]/);
if (r)
    console.log(r[0]); //=> "[丹]"
```

If you want just the character inside the brackets, use a [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

```
var r = '[丹]'.match(/\[(\u4e39)]/);
if (r)
    console.log(r[1]); //=> "丹"
```